# using ren does not give me the results i expected

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

Below is my dir command:

```
03/02/2016  02:25 PM    <DIR>          .
03/02/2016  02:25 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/01/2016  05:28 PM               342 agent_comp.css
03/01/2016  05:27 PM             1,581 agent_comp.dart
03/01/2016  05:25 PM             3,017 agent_comp.html
03/01/2016  04:54 PM               343 array_comp.css
03/01/2016  05:02 PM             1,965 array_comp.dart
03/01/2016  05:02 PM             2,191 array_comp.html
03/01/2016  04:54 PM               343 server_comp.css
03/01/2016  05:11 PM             1,481 server_comp.dart
03/01/2016  05:16 PM             2,033 server_comp.html
03/02/2016  01:04 PM             1,542 system_status_comp.dart
03/01/2016  04:52 PM               647 system_status_comp.html
          11 File(s)         15,485 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  223,731,183,616 bytes free
```

and my goal is to strip `_comp` from all the filenames

I was trying `ren *_* *.*` but that doesnt work.

My thought process was that in an example:

```
ren *_* *_NEW.*
```

replaces all `_comp` with `_NEW`

so i was thinking to just remove that from the second argument as above, but it doesnt work as I wanted.

Where did my logic fault me?  My bet is that the regex somehow was lazy and just ended up renaming it to exactly what it was.

Any clue?

Comment: oh, wrong sub.  Thanks, ill edit.

Comment: You cannot do what you want with a single REN command. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](http://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*%~1*" '
) DO (
 SET "filename=%%~na"
 SET "filename=!filename:%~1=!"
 ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!filename!%%~xa"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

run

```
*thisbatch* _comp
```

to delete the string "_comp" from the filenames.

Read each filename matching the mask, substitute *nothing* for the string specified as %1

BTW, changing to

```
 SET "filename=!filename:%~1=%~2!"
```

should replace the first supplied string with the second in filenames, so

```
*thisbatch* _comp
```

would delete the string "_comp" from the filenames.

and

```
*thisbatch* _comp abcd
```

would replace "_comp" with "abcd"